# How do I save a specific AC3 audio channel from an iTunes FairPlay protected movie?

Tags: macos, itunes, audio

I am wondering how can I save a specific AC3 audio channel from an iTunes DRM protected movie ? Right now the AC3 audio source is greyed out !
*I am on Mavericks !*

Comment: There is a reason for protection?  Are you asking the Boonie & Clyde question?

Comment: ok Bonnie :) what is the link to the movie?

Comment: No, there is no reason ! I was just telling that FYI.

Comment: sometimes a search for soundtrack or subtitles can be helpful.

Comment: Isn't there an other way than finding alternate soundtrack ? I thought to Soundflower to emulate a Dolby Digital output and then saving this sound using GarageBand but the last time I tried it it didn't work because the AC3 soundtrack was greyed out !